# SQL Server 2005 support for Oracle-style autonmous transaction

Tags: sql-server, transactions

Within a transaction is there a way to have data committed within it even though the transaction is rolled back? We're writing audit/logging information inside a transaction but we want to keep that information even though the transaction has to roll back.

We've see an [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/john_charles/SimulatingautonomoustransactionsinMicrosoftSQLServer10092008132945PM/SimulatingautonomoustransactionsinMicrosoftSQLServer.aspx) that tries to copy the Oracle way but what we're really looking for is some in-built SQL Server support (and was hoping for something like a 'not supported' option for a sproc or a 'suspend transaction' command.) Google searches have been a bit hopeless hence this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this may be the only way but for SQL Server 2008, but it does mention options for SQL Server 2005

[How to create an autonomous transaction in SQL Server 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlprogrammability/archive/2008/08/22/how-to-create-an-autonomous-transaction-in-sql-server-2008.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft considered the idea in a simpler approach for 2008 and then dropped it:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=296870

but there is another work around on their website.